# Regex exception for multiple format

Tags: java, sql

I have a regex to avoid 'sql' in my error code.

Regex I use is :`java.(?!sql).*Exception`

one of the example of error with sql is:`java.sql.SQLException`

Now in the same regex I need to avoid the following error where `AbstractUnmarshallerImpl` and `createUnmarshal` is unique to this error.

> javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException

I need to modify the same `regex:java.(?!sql).*Exception`, to avoid bothe errors.

Comment: I don’t understand how using a regular expression can avoid an error.  Edit your question and add some code that demonstrates how it can be done.

Comment: Some code and an example would probably clarify this question a lot

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the code:
Regex I use is :java.(?!sql).*Exception

Comment: It’s still very unclear what you want to do here and what your regex is supposed to match.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson
My regex should not match following error exceptions:
java.sql.SQLException and 
javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException.
Looks like I figured it out:
java.(?!sql|(.*.*.(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl))).*Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out. Thanks for looking in to it.

Solution is: `java.(?!sql|(.*.*.(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl))).*Exception`

Comment: Note that `.` will match _any_ character, and that you need `\.` to match a _literal_ `.`